# Spring-Security OAuth2 setup - unable to locate oauth2 namespace handler

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to setup our REST server for OAuth2 with spring-security. (The server already supports spring-security without OAuth). Now I tried to follow the sparklr example and added the spring-security-oauth artifact to my maven (mvn dependency:tree shows it is available) as well as the namespace configuration to my spring-security-context.xml but all I get is:

```
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2]
```

Browsing to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/` all I see are the .xsd files but no oauth2 folder.. How can that be? I am assuming the sparklr example is a working version, so what am I doing wrong?

Here's my spring-security-context header:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
```

If needed, here's the maven setup:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: update: https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You referer to OAuth2 but import the OAuth 1. replace the dependency to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Aww hell, why is it that after posting a question after endless searching you do just one more search and find the answer?! Just found it at http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?121522-quot-Unable-to-locate-Spring-NamespaceHandler-quot-for-OAuth-2-XSD but thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that spring-security-oauth2 jar is present in classpath and it will work

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```